# how to import formsmodules in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8, angular-forms

working with Angular 8 and I have import FormsModule in app.module.ts like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

then I got following message
`Module '"../../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'FormsModule'.ts(2305)`

then how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be [`@angular/forms`](https://angular.io/api/forms):

Change import with below:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```